# I can't addDoc in firebasefirestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add my data to firestore i make it by follow the tutorial on youtube but i got the error

> Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore

[like this (img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGn5w.png)

[image: this is my firestore]

Under function `addq()` I get this code from Firebase documentation:

```
import {
  getFirestore, doc, getDoc, setDoc, collection, addDoc, updateDoc, deleteDoc, deleteField
}from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.19.1/firebase-firestore.js";

const db = getDatabase();

async function addq(){
  const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "QD"), {
    Room: 2,
    Time: "3:30",
    State: "CPT",
  });
}
```

And this one from tutorial on youtube:

```
import {
  getFirestore, doc, getDoc, setDoc, collection, addDoc, updateDoc, deleteDoc, deleteField
}from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.0/firebase-firestore.js";

const db = getDatabase();

async function addq(){
  var ref = collection(db, 'QD');

  const docRef = await addDoc(
    ref, {
      Room: 2,
      Time: "3:30",
      State: "CPT",
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`getDatabase()` method is used to get a reference to the `Realtime Database` but since you are using firestore you should reference the `Firestore Database` using `getFirestore()`. Check the code below.

```
const db = getFirestore();
```

Check the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) for further information.